# Polymorphic pointer change at run time

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I am really confused about polymorphic pointers. I have 2 classes derived from an interface as shown below code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base  {

public:
    virtual ~Base() { }
    virtual void addTest() = 0;
};

class B: public Base {

public:
    B(){}
    ~B(){}

    void addTest(){
        cout << "Add test B\n";
    }
};
class C: public Base {

public:
    C(){}
   ~C(){}

    void addTest(){
        cout << "Add test C\n";
    }
private:   
    void deleteTest(){
        
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    Base *base = new B();
    base->addTest();
    base = new C();
    base->addTest();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to change the pointer dynamically according to a condition at run time to use the same pointer with different kinds of scenarios.

Derived classes are different from each other, so what happens in memory when the polymorphic pointer object changes?

If that usage is not good practice, how can I change the polymorphic pointer object dynamically at the run time?

Comment: What is the question? Is this the question? "what happens in memory when the polymorphic pointer object changes?"

Comment: I suspect that you're assuming that it is much more complicated than it is. All that happens is that `base` is assigned a different value - the location of the newly-created `C` - instead of its original value. That is, it is no more complicated than `int x = 1; x = 2;`.

Comment: @user253751 yes, one of the questions is that.

Comment: Well this is *a* question not more than one question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to *change what a pointer points to*. A `Base*` is not an instance of `Base`, it is a pointer that *points to* an instance of a `Base` (or something derived from it -- in this case `B` or `C`).

Thus in your code, `base = new B()` sets it to point to a new instance of a `B`, and then `base = new C()` sets it to point to a new instance of a `C`.

> Derived classes are different from each other, so what happens in memory when the polymorphic pointer object changes?

Because `Base*` *points to* an instance of a `Base`, all this is doing is changing which instance (or derived instance) `Base*` points to. In effect, it just changes the memory address of the pointer.

From that `Base*` pointer, you still have access to anything defined in that `Base` class -- which still allows polymorphic calls to functions satisfied by derived types if the function is defined as `virtual`.

The exact mechanism for how this is dispatched to derived types is technically an implementation-detail of the language, but generally this is done through a process called double-dispatch, which uses a "V-Table". This is additional type-information stored alongside any classes that contain `virtual` functions (it's conceptually just a `struct` of function pointers, where the function pointers are satisfied by the concrete types).

See: [Why do we need a virtual table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3004501/1678770) for more information on vtables.

---

What is problematic, however, is the use of `new` here. `new` allocates memory that must be cleaned up with `delete` to avoid a memory leak. By doing the following:

```cpp
Base *base = new B();
base->addTest();
base = new C(); // overwriting base without deleting the old instance
base->addTest();
```

The `B` object's destructor is never run, no resources are cleaned up, and the memory for `B` itself is never reclaimed. This should be:

```cpp
Base *base = new B();
base->addTest();
delete base;
base = new C(); // overwriting base without deleting the old instance
base->addTest();
delete base;
```

Or, better yet, this should be using smart-pointers like `std::unique_ptr` to do this for you. In which case you don't use `new` and `delete` explicitly, you use `std::make_unique` for allocation, and the destructor automagically does this for you:

```cpp
auto base = std::make_unique<B>();
base->addTest();
base = std::make_unique<C>(); // destroy's the old instance before reassigning
base->addTest();
```

This is the recommended/modern way to write dynamic allocations

Comment: I feel like this answer focuses too much on memory leaks and not enough on polymorphism. While the memory leak is a problem, I want to be clear that `delete` and `make_unique` aren't part of polymorphism.

Comment: @user253751 That's fair; I've expanded on the polymorphic aspect, though IMO the real important part of the answer is that a `Base*` is a pointer and not an instance of `Base` specifically.