# Why does a pure virtual member function have to be virtual?

Tags: c++, interface, language-lawyer, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have a question regarding the declaration of pure virtual functions in C++. I come from a Java background, and so I see pure virtual functions as a way to define abstract classes and the idea of interfaces. My question is simple, when we define a pure virtual function in C++ we have to write something like this:

`virtual void function() =0`

The void could be of any type, but we have to include the equals to 0 and the virtual keyword. I understand the "equals to 0" part as being used to define a pure function, but my question is why does it have to be virtual? Couldn't we just define it without the virtual keyword? Is this just a part of C++ that is included in the definition of pure virtual functions or is there a logical reason as to why "abstract methods" must be virtual as well?

Comment: In Java all methods in interface are implicitly virtual. In C++ there is not special keyword for interfaces so there is no implicit `virtual` for any method (except for those which are virtual in base class). `= 0` is information for compiler that he doesn't have to look for implementation of given method (you can provide it).

Comment: If you don't specify it `virtual`, it will be ordinary member function, which does not support run-time polymorphism. Only if you specify it virtual, thus the address of it will be placed into [virtual table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004501/why-do-we-need-a-virtual-table), and won't be hard-coded at compilation, which support the program run-time polymorphism

Comment: Ummm .... not all non-static member functions are `virtual` (unlike some other languages like Java).   A virtual function is one that *can* be overridden by a derived class.   A pure virtual function is one that *must* be overridden by a derived class if the derived class must be able to be instantiated (ie. be instantiable).   A pure function (one that must be overridden, if the derived class is to be instantiable) that is not virtual (can be hidden but not overridden by a derived class) is simply a contradiction.

Comment: If you have "an abstract function" that is not virtual, the derived class cannot implement it. You can use `= delete` for such a function.

Comment: Is your question just about syntax, i.e `= 0` would imply `virtual`? (a little as we don't have to write `virtual` when we write `override`/`final`).

Comment: "_I come from a Java background_" So you intuitions are more likely incorrect than correct if you think in term of Java categories; Java doesn't have MI (multiple inheritance) and C++ doesn't have interfaces. An abstract class is absolutely a class, a user defined data type, you just need to derive it before you have a chance to instantiate it. It isn't just that abstract classes can be stateful, stateless classes are still not "interfaces". An abstract class is a special polymorphic class. It follows *all the rules of polymorphic classes.*

Comment: @MarekR in Java, all *abstract* methods are implicitly virtual. So this still applies to the OP’s question which is about an abstract method but this nuance is important as nowadays, interfaces can have private and static methods which are not virtual.

Answer (score 2):

A non-virtual pure function doesn't make much sense.
Fundamentally, a function is a named section of code that can be called in some way. If you make it pure, that means there is (possibly) no section of code at all; there is only the name.

This does make sense for `virtual` member functions because the implementation could be provided by one of the derived classes. Even if `Base::foo()` doesn't exist, it's possible that calling `Base::foo()` will call `Derived::foo()` through dynamic dispatch. However, without `virtual`, no such mechanism exists.

Similarly, `abstract final` methods don't make much sense in Java. A non-virtual member function in C++ can be considered `final` since there is no mechanism for overriding it.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it have to be virtual? Couldn't we just define it without the virtual keyword?

The answer is, no. The mechanism of a virtual member function and an ordinary member function are quite different.

### How a member function works

A member function's address is determined at the link period by the linker.

[Check this code](https://godbolt.org/z/G36s4E5Ps). In this piece of code, after linking, the `void Test::member(void)` part in `call    void Test::member(void)` will be replaced by a real offset address, which means it's hard-coded. No matter whether there are derived classes, if you call `member()` on a reference/pointer of a `Test`, the function to be called is determined.

Yet it's not how virtual functions work in C++.

### How a virtual member function works

In C++, if a class has virtual functions, it will have a [virtual table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004501/why-do-we-need-a-virtual-table). TLDR, here is a small example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Test {
  virtual void test() = 0;
};

int main() { 
  std::cout << "sizeof(Test): " << sizeof(Test) << std::endl; 
}
```

```
sizeof(Test): 8
```

Although `Test` is empty, it contains a pointer to the virtual table, which makes it possible for polymorphism.

By specifying a function `virtual`, only the compiler will put the address of the function's address into the virtual table, instead of replacing the call statement with a hard-coded function address.

Whenever you declare a virtual function, an item will be created in the vtable. In this example, once you declare `Test::test`, the first item will store the function address of `Test::test`, yet since it's a pure virtual function, the content of the item might be `nullptr` or whatever, depending on the implementation of compiler. Once you derive a class from `Test`, let's say `Derived`, and overridden `test` in `Derived`, the first item's content will be updated with the address of `Derived::test`.

When you get a pointer/reference of `Test`, and try to call `test` function of the object, the program will first get the first item in the vtable, get the address of `<ObjectType>::test`'s address, then call the function at that address.

Here is a small example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
  virtual void test() = 0;
};

class Derived_A : public Test {
public:
  virtual void test() override { std::cout << "A::" << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

class Derived_B : public Test {
public:
  virtual void test() override { std::cout << "B::" << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "sizeof(Test): " << sizeof(Test) << std::endl;

  Derived_A a;
  Derived_B b;

  long *vtable = (long *)(&a);          // get vtable address
  long *first_item = (long *)(*vtable); // get the address of the first item
  void (*func)() = (void (*)())(*first_item);
}
```

result:

```
sizeof(Test): 8
A::test
```

Since we get `Derived_A`'s vtable's address, the function we called with the first item of the table is `Derived_A::test`. Yet if you use the same method to operate on a `Derived_B`'s vtable, you will call `Derived_B::test`, and that's how polymorphism works in C++.